# How to convert multiple 19 Digit Snapchat.jpg files to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, time, datetime-format, snapchat

I have a list of strings that have various 19digits (& 10 digits) in a row that MAY signify a meaningful datetime. I am unable to convert this into a useable datetime.

**Does anyone know if the snapchat file saved format (i.e. snapchat-1234567890123456789.jpg) have any rhyme or reason to it?**

The file-format comes from old saved personal snapchat photos titles that I'm trying to organize; unfortunately there is no associated EXIF data - just the title.

18/19 Digit examples include:

- Snapchat-3201324732883372891 - which equates to Jan 17th, 2016.
- Snapchat-2026690704509960542 - which equates to Nov 8th, 2016.
- Snapchat-8887179640815077729 - which equates to ~Oct 31st, 2016.

But then on newer dates, I have 10 digit file formats:

- Snapchat-915670844 - which equates to ~Jan 2022
- Snapchat-363015577 - which equates to ~Dec 2022

I've scoured the internet and snapchat API page. No luck.  Open to any suggestions.

If anyone has experience processing Snapchat photos, please feel free to add any commentary.

One of the many links that I tried to establish some sort of linear relationship which I do not see: [19 Digit Timestamp Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62291324/19-digit-timestamp-conversion)

Comment: This doesn't look like a date format TBH. Unless some math is done before turning it into a date, it doesn't make sense to have newer dates have a lower number than older dates. There is no linear progression. I would say this is some kind of UUID.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking... My guess is it's some sort of UUID possibly with some sort of hash. I did a bunch of googling but did not see really much of anyone trying to process their saved snapchat.jpgs.   Appreciate the response.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.